# Company hierarchy class diagram

Tags: oop, uml

I want to create an UML class diagram of a company hierarchy and I want to especially to mention that every employee has a superior in the hierarchy (for exemple every department in a company has chief and a chief is a superior of other employees in the departement ).
I build this diagram but I feel that there is some thing wrong
[image]

Comment: Two primary things: a) remove the `<<Class>>` stereotype. b) replace the Generalizations (non-filled triangles) with simple associations (just leave the triangle away or make it an open arrow if you feel better with directed assocs.).

Comment: thanks Mr Thomas,can you tell me about the logic of the diagram,Is the logic of the diagram compatible with my description of the problem?

Comment: I would, but your description has an endless recursion. If every employee has ONE superior, then where does that end?

Comment: I want that  in every departement we have a chief of departement who is superior than normal workers and the PDG is superor than all the chiefs of departement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would omit every generalization, it leads to hell (imagine simple situation - you have a hospital with doctors and patients. How many instances of one person will you have, if a doctor brakes his ankle and becomes a patient? And now you decide to have a library. A doctor can borrow a book as well as a patient.). Anyway, I would depict your domain as is at the diagram below (with example).

[image]

As for you requirement: I want especially to mention that every employee has a superior in the hierarchy. It is not feasible in a real world. So I use 0..1 multiplicity.

Comment: What tool have you used to draw the diagram? It looks nice.

Comment: @sergej Sparx Enterprise Architect

Answer (score 1):

According to your description I'd come up with this:

[image]

A `Department` is composed of `Employee`s. A `Chief` is an `Employee` and there's exactly one `Chief` per `Department`.

There are definitely other ways to model this. Especially the generalization might be done in different ways. This depends on lots of domain details which can't be discussed here. But basically you could start with this approach.